# What Ver. of Ubuntu Server Distor is Webmin 1.470 fits for?

Tags: ubuntu

Webmin 1.470 Platform is Cross Linux Compatible, but there are some issues regarding bug.
The question is : What Ver. of Ubuntu Server Distor is Webmin 1.470 fits for?

Thanks.

Comment: Which bugs? Do you have any references and which versions have you already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu isn't very keen on webmin -- see [this mailing list post](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2006-September/020471.html) for example. Unless you really have to use webmin, you may be better off with eBox, which is officially supported and discussed in the Ubuntu Server Guide.